Given: $\tan x + \tan^2 x + \tan^3 x = 1$ Find the value of: $2 \cos^6 x - 2 \cos^4 x + \cos^2 x$
I have tried using double angle formula of cosine function, $\cos(2x) = \frac{1-\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}$ and $\cos^2(x) = \frac{1}{1+\tan^2x}$, Found the value of $\cos^2x$ and tried to equate the values as in $\frac{\tan x+1}{2} = \frac{1}{1+\tan^2x}$
How can I find the numerical value mathematically without the use of a calculator?

This question is similar to: Find the value of $2\cos ^6 x -2\cos ^4 x+\cos ^2 x$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search.

We can use the identity $1+\tan^2 x=\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}$ to get
\begin{align*}
2&=1+\left(\tan x+\tan^2 x+\tan^3 x\right)\\
&=\left(1+\tan^2 x\right)+\tan x\left(1+\tan^2 x\right)\\
&=(1+\tan x)\left(1+\tan^2 x\right)\\
&=\frac{1+\tan x}{\cos^2 x}.
\end{align*}
Hence
$$\cos^2 x=\frac{1+\tan x}{2}.$$
Substituting this into the expression of cosines we find
$$2\cos^6 x-2\cos^4 x+\cos^2 x=\frac{1}{4}\left(1+\tan x+\tan^2 x+\tan^3 x\right)=\frac{1}{2}.$$

This is a bit tricky question. But yes, it's easy.
First of all look at the $1^{st}$ condition which is $$\tan(x)+\tan^{2}(x)+\tan^{3}(x)=1$$
Now from this condition you can easily say that $$\tan(x)+\tan^{3}(x)=1-\tan^{2}(x)$$
Which implies $$\tan(x)(1+\tan^{2}(x))=1-\tan^{2}(x)$$
Which implies $$\tan(x)\sec^{2}(x)=1-\tan^{2}(x)$$
Which implies $$\tan(x)\sec^{2}(x)=\frac{\cos(2x)}{\cos^{2}(x)}$$
Which implies $$\tan(x)=\cos(2x)$$
Now you have to find the value of $$2\cos^{6}(x)-2\cos^{4}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)$$
Now let's assume $$y=2\cos^{6}(x)-2\cos^{4}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)$$
$$\implies y=2\cos^{4}(x)[\cos^{2}(x)-1]+\cos^{2}(x)$$
$$\implies y=2\cos^{4}(x)[-\sin^{2}(x)]+\cos^{2}(x)$$
$$\implies y=\frac{-\cos^{2}(x)4\sin^{2}(x)\cos^{2}(x)}{2}+\cos^{2}(x)$$
$$\implies y=\frac{-\cos^{2}(x)\sin^{2}(2x)}{2}+\cos^{2}(x)$$
$$\implies y=\cos^{2}(x)\left(\frac{2-\sin^{2}(2x)}{2}\right)$$
$$\implies y=\cos^{2}(x)\left(\frac{1+\cos^{2}(2x)}{2}\right)$$
$$\implies y=\frac{\cos^{2}(x)×\sec^{2}(x)}{2}$$
$$\implies y=\frac{1}{2}$$
Therefore $$2\cos^{6}(x)-2\cos^{4}(x)+\cos^{2}(x)=\frac{1}{2}$$
